# ASP.NET with C# Facebook Comment Integration

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook

I'll be needing an Facebook integration to my ASP.NET website. And I would like to know how can I make an integration like in the image below.

What are the key points I have to pay attention; Like, When the user see this page WITHOUT facebook login at that time?

Is there an API for this? Or if not could you just help me with an example code or project?

Thank you very much.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK.. May be I acted too early to ask this question before I check up on Facebook development section..

Even though I hate facebook for many reasons :), this particular problem is solved pretty easy and here is what I have done;

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
            <script type="text/javascript">    

        var AppID = '207720000000004'; //My FB App ID
                         $(document).ready(function() {
                             FBHelper.init(AppID);


                         });

            (function (d, s, id) {
                    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                    if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
                    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
                    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=207720000000004"; //My FB App ID
                    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
                } (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

    </script>


    <fb:comments href="http://www.mydomain.com/campaigns/mycampaign.aspx" num_posts="2" width="500"></fb:comments>
```